# localStorage не может запомнить переменную

Tags: javascript, localstorage

Есть код:

```
    <script>

            document.querySelector('.fon1').onclick = function() {                  
                var fon = {1};                      
            }
            document.querySelector('.fon2').onclick = function() {                  
                var fon = {2};                      
            }
            document.querySelector('.fon3').onclick = function() {                  
                var fon = {3};                      
            }
            var sObj = JSON.stringify(fon)
            localStorage.setItem("object", sObj)
            localStorage.object
            var retObj = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("object"))

        </script>
```

И

```
<a href="#">
                <div class="fon1">
                    <img src="/images/main3.jpg" alt="текст">
                    <for>Текст1</for>   
                    <for1>Текст2</for1> 
                </div>
            </a>    
            <a href="#">
                <div class="fon2">
                    <img src="/images/main3.jpg" alt="текст">
                    <for>Текст1</for>   
                    <for1>Текст2</for1>                     
                </div>
            </a>    
            <a href="#">
                <div class="fon3">
                    <img src="/images/main3.jpg" alt="текст">
                    <for>Текст1</for>   
                    <for1>Текст2</for1>                     
                </div>
            </a>
```

Так вот почему-то переменная `fon` не может запомниться. Т.е. когда я вынимаю переменную на другой странице:

```
localStorage.object


       var retObj = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("object"))
if(retObj != "1") { } else if(retObj != "2") { }
```

Он считает, что это число "1". Хотя я до этого нажал на `div` класса "`fon2`" и `alert` мне выдал, что `fon` теперь равен "2". В чем может быть проблема? По сути же, переменная изменилась и далее сохранилась в переменную

Comment: `localStorage.object` ??

Comment: Сам не понял, но увидел на сайте и решил добавить навсякий :)

Comment: я новичок в работе с LS)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ваш код не записывает измененное значение в `localStorage`.

```
var fon = 0;                      
function SaveFon() {
  localStorage.setItem("object", fon)
}
document.querySelector('.fon1').onclick = function() {                  
  fon = 1;
  SaveFon();
}
document.querySelector('.fon2').onclick = function() {                  
  fon = 2;
  SaveFon();
}
document.querySelector('.fon3').onclick = function() {                  
  fon = 3;
  SaveFon();
}
```

Comment: Да, все заработало, спасибо!)